# Show user-friendly name in pkexec

Tags: pkexec

I am trying to make pkexec show my program's user-friendly name rather than its path. For example, Synaptic Package Manager says "Synaptic Package Manager," rather than "/usr/sbin/synaptic" in its dialogs. How could I do this?

Comment: My *guess* is that you can't, as it would be a security problem. You could make it show `/usr/bin/gedit`, when you're in reality running `rootshell.bin`

Comment: When I start, say, Synaptic, it says "Synaptic Package Manager" instead of a path. That is what I was referring to.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and elaborate a bit on what you currently see and what you're trying to achieve as now it's **unclear what you're asking...**

Comment: Suggestion: Take a screenshot of the pkexec dialog (of Synaptic, for example), then indicate which part you want the "user-friendly name" to appear: Title bar? Main window area (the body text)? Collapsible window area (where the full path is found)? An annotated screenshot would be useful to show what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As regards Synaptic I think the 'secret' lies in this file:

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic.policy
```

Comment: How could I do that in my own dialogs?

Comment: @Someone: I would have looked at the source code for Synaptic or some other program which does it the same way.